# How do I include another file in an httpHandler?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, httphandler

I'm creating a webhandler and want to include classes from another file.  How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "include classes from another file" ?

Comment: I'm converting a page (.aspx) to a handler (.ashx).  In my .aspx I used `<!--#include file="other file.aspx"-->` to include custom classes from the other file in the .aspx.  That syntax doesn't work in the .ashx.

Comment: Check the answer below.  The problem is that `.aspx` files are not compiled in such a way that you can reference them from another file, so you have to do a little refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the code from the `.aspx` file to a `.vb` file.  If the `.vb` file is not in the same project as the `.ashx` file, then compile the file into an assembly and reference the assembly in the project where the `.ashx` exists.  Then you can instantiate the classes in the `vb` file in your `ashx`.

Comment: That looks to be the solution.  Thank you so much... I was really tearing my hair out over this one!

Answer (score 0):

Include those projects as references in the project that has the HTTPHandler, and then refer to those classes in code; make sure you have the appropriate using namespace definitions defined.

If this doesn't help, please elaborate on the problem.

HTH.

Comment: I'm actually not using Visual Studio - just a text editor.  Is there a syntax to accomplish the same thing with a directive or other such beast?